Connection string with AzureKeyVault - Hybrid Blazor app
Used the local SQL connection string for development, starting testing and added KeyVault storage for the connection string in Azure...
So in the project appsettings.json contains the connection string to Azure:
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnectionLocal": "@AzureKeyVault(ConnectionStrings--DefaultConnection)"
},

"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Information",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
"AllowedHosts": "*"

}
and with appsettings.Development.json:
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=MY_LOCAL_SERVER\\SQLEXPRESS;..."
},
  "DetailedErrors": true,
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR": "Debug"
    }
  }
}

Program.cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var keyVaultEndpoint = new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VaultUri"));
builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultEndpoint, new DefaultAzureCredential());

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyComponents();

builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IdentityUserAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IdentityRedirectManager>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, 
PersistingRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
    })
    .AddIdentityCookies();


var conn = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
...

Without this line on Progam.cs
builder
   .Configuration
   .AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultEndpoint, new DefaultAzureCredential());

Load local connection string again...
What would be the correct way to use environment variables with Azure Key Vault in Blazor hybrid applications? (Without having to comment any line of code for test environments)

I think this answer would also solve your problem here.

If we run the application via VS, then it has configurations "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development" in launchsetting.json to indicate the development environment, then the application will use appsettings.Development.json just like you know. And we can also try codes similar to var app = builder.Build(); if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) in Program.cs to make sure the application is using development configuration.

Thanks decius i create mix solution ;D

Tiny Wang, in this case I need to know before the construction of the "app" variable if the environment is production

Finally the solution has been a mix of several answers, including decius suggestion in the comments.
I have removed the connection string from the appsettings.json file
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {        
},
...

Same appsettings.Development.json:
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=MY_LOCAL_SERVER\\SQLEXPRESS;..."
},
...

And created a new appsettings.Production.json file:
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=MY_PRODUCTION_SERVER\\SQLEXPRESS;..."
},
...

With this, the part of loading the correct connection string is already solved.
To solve quickly, in hybrid environments that are the local testing environment, the "IsLocal" variable is added to the profile.
And to avoid loading the secrets credentials locally (I don't use them locally for anything else) I avoid loading from program.cs (check this answer too):
if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("IsLocal") == "False")
{
    var keyVaultEndpoint = new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VaultUri"));
    builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultEndpoint, new DefaultAzureCredential());
}

Don't forget to set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable with the same name, in this case "Production" in the final environment
